# Как разбить число на разряды

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть число `1234567`.
Как разбить пробелами число по разрядам, чтобы получилось `1 234 567`?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
x = 1234567
'{0:,}'.format(x).replace(',', ' ')

>>> '1 234 567'
```

Comment: как это работает?

Comment: `{0:,}` - указываем запятую в качестве разделителя разрядов и заменяем ее в получившейся строке на пробелы

Answer (score 10):

Если хочется сгруппировать тысячи в числе в соответствии с текущей локалью пользователя:

```
>>> import locale
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
'ru_RU.UTF-8'
>>> print(locale.format('%d', 1234567, grouping=True))
1 234 567
```

В другой локали, разделитель может быть другим:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
'en_US.UTF-8'
>>> print(locale.format('%d', 1234567, grouping=True))
1,234,567
```

Имена локалей и доступная функциональность могут зависеть от системы.

Answer (score 3):

так можно любую маску сделать по количеству разрядов

```
import re

def numberjump_filter(string):
    string=str(string)
    #s = re.match("(\d{0,})(\d{3})(\d{4})",string)
    s = re.match("(.*)(\d\d\d)(\d\d\d\d)",string)
    return s[1]+" "+s[2]+" "+s[3]
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё вариант для разнообразия:

```
n = str(1234567)[::-1]
print(' '.join(n[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(n), 3))[::-1])
```

- делаем из числа строку
- переворачиваем её
- отрезаем по три символа
- объединяем их через пробелы
- ещё раз переворачиваем то, что получилось

Вывод:

```
1 234 567
```

Answer (score 3):

Разбиваем на разряды, при этом используем f-string:

```
x = 1234567890
print(f"{x:_} руб.".replace("_", " "))
```

Разумеется, надо учитывать, будут ли в тексте ещё символы `_` , которые могут быть заменены на пробелы. В этом случае лучше вынести f-string в отдельную переменную и использовать её в коде.

```
x = 1234567890
fstring = f"{x:_} руб.".replace("_", " ")
print(f"Итого: {fstring} \n Напишите сумму прописью: ________________")
```

Comment: Строго говоря, это то же что и в [принятом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/545839/1365), только через f-строки вместо format. Но работает точно так же.

Comment: Не спорю, но я искал именно через f-string, не нашёл, поэтому когда получилось реализовать, дополнил. f-string новичкам воспринимать проще, чем формат.